# Ubuntu MySQL won't start because disk is full, but it isn't

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I've a Linode with Ubuntu (12.04.4 LTS) installed. The HDD is 200GB but when I log-in via SSH, it tells me this:

```
Usage of /:   99.1% of 8.83GB
```

MySQL fails to start because there is no free space... but how is that possible if my HDD is 200GB and only 19GB are occupied?!? What do I have to do to fix it and maybe make more than 8GB available?

Thanks.

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda       596848 186038  410810   32% /
devtmpfs       1025776   1400 1024376    1% /dev
none           1026021    809 1025212    1% /run
none           1026021      2 1026019    1% /run/lock
none           1026021      3 1026018    1% /run/shm
overflow       1026021      2 1026019    1% /tmp
```

Comment: What file system are you using? How is the disk formatted and partitioned?

Comment: what does `df -i` report?

Comment: I've updated the question with the results from df -i